# Trying to read and use data from a JSON file

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to import a JSON file into my Angular typescript page file that looks like:

```
{
    "latitude": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 
    "longitude": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    "value":[53, 95, 3, 10, 239, 102, 604, 58, 82, 105, 220, 68]
}
```

I'm new to this, so from a tutorial online I used HttpClient to go through the file and move data into arrays for usage in another function.

```
latitudes = [];
  
constructor(private http: HttpClient) 
  { 
    // grab the data from the json file and creates a JSON object
    this.http.get('../../assets/data/test2.json').toPromise().then(data => 
    {
      for( let key in data)
      {
        // checks if data has a key
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key))
        {
          // check if key = latitude, if true then push current data to latitude list
          if(key == "latitude")
          {
            this.latitudes.push(key);
            this.latitudes.push(data[key]);
          }
        }
      }


      console.log(this.latitudes);
    });

    console.log(this.latitudes);
  }
```

And while it does get the data, when trying to access the latitudes list, the console.log inside the http get request is able to use the data freely. However, when outside I am unable to access the data despite it still sort of showing up on console.log, and when trying to access the data from the outside, it is saying it is undefined. I was hoping to be able to use this data for making a visualization later.

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDmXw.png)

In the picture, the top is output from the outside, and the one below is from inside. Reading around I heard it's because of a synchronization issue or something? Since the console output is in that order, is it because the outer output is running before the inner one?

Comment: When dealing with async/Promise calls, you only have the data at the time the `.then` is executed, which is almost certain to not be immediately after the call is started (e.g. the `console.log` outside the `.then`). There are plenty of related questions related to this.

Comment: The question [Is it bad practice to have a constructor function return a Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398699/is-it-bad-practice-to-have-a-constructor-function-return-a-promise) is not quite the same as yours but the accepted answer explains why the call shouldn't be in the constructor and how to do it instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this is a simple way:

```
this.http.get('../../assets/data/test2.json').toPromise().then(data => 
    {
      Object.keys(data)?.forEach(key => {
        if(key === "latitude") {
          this.latitudes = data[key];
        }
      });

      console.log(this.latitudes);
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything for the actual problem: _"However, when outside I am unable to access the data"_